# Getting driver license in Washington, moving from Canada (BC) on class 7?

Tags: usa, driving-license

I live in British Columbia (BC) and I have class 7 license. I am moving to Seattle on a TN visa and I'm wondering if I can also exchange the class 7 license for the full Washington license without additional testing? I ask this because I am in a rush to get auto insurance from Washington state and I need a local driver license to avoid extra charges. I am in a rush to get auto insurance because I will be on a temporary 1-week auto insurance policy from BC.

According to the DMV website, it seems like I can?

http://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/moving.html

On that note, I am getting a temporary 1-week auto insurance in BC, since the old one will expire soon. When I get my license in Washington, do I have to turn in my BC license? Would my BC auto insurance still cover me when I don't have my BC license?

Comment: You should check whether your BC insurance will cover you at all in the US.

Comment: Which DMV in Washington did you go to?

Comment: I think I went to Bel-Red Auto License in Bellevue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great news everybody! I just got my BC class 7 license exchanged for the full Washington one!

Comment: Could you ellaborate whether it was straightforward to do this, or if you'd had some issues in the process?

Comment: It was straight forward. Go to the DMV and tell them you have a BC license and you want to switch it to the Washington one. Just make sure you have all the required documents with you!

Comment: So now you can switch it back to a full Canadian license. Sounds like a great loophole :)